# Magento 2: Override file app/lib/web/mage/validation.js

Tags: magento2, validation, error-message

How to override file `app/lib/web/mage/validation.js`?

I want to change the System Error Message in this JS file.

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override it by placing it under your custom theme on the below path.

```
/app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/web/mage/validation.js
```

After placing this file, please run the below commands to reflect the changes.

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: Thanks! its work! I think I didn't do all steps of  CLI

Comment: Yes, its just for make sure for removing the cache and static files from the website.

Answer (score 1):

Go to this path and override you want to file:-

```
/app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme_Name]/web/mage/validation.js
```

you put override the file after the run some command :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

Hope this help

Thanks ...